# How to update the selected item after being re-directed into another page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Im creating an app where I have used ionic item-divider. When I click on the list header it will re-direct to the new view where the user can update and delete the currently selected item.The problem I face is in the updation because Im unable to push the information from the first page to the second page i.e I want to push both the selected item and its sub-item so that both are edited and saved. Im using `key` in my controller to know what is being selected, after which I'm struggling to push the option selected and its related information to the next page for update and save it. I have attached a plunker how my first page looks.

[plnkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/SmbVhUnNCH4qbcrcpXNR?p=info)

Main View:

```
   <ion-list>
   <ion-item ng-model="carBrand" ng-repeat="name in carSelect">       
   <button ng-click="selectItem(name)">{{name.name}}</button>
   <div class="item" ng-repeat="type in name.types">{{type}}</div>
   </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you are doing wrong
you cant use

```
$state.go('second.html',{key});
```

It needs proper routing,You cant use explicit .html file to go to. You should add config part in your js like this

```
carService.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

   .state('first', {
      url: '/first',
      templateUrl: 'templates/first.html',
      controller: 'carBrand'
    })
     .state('second', {
      url: '/second',
      templateUrl: 'templates/second.html',
      controller: 'secondCTRL',
      params: {
          object: null
      }
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/first');
})
```

after that you can only goto secong page . And for passing parameters 
you should pass it through like this

```
$state.go('second', {object:key});
```

but you are using $rootScope so you dont need to pass parameters , You can use that $rootScope.selectItem in your secondController.

Hope This helps You .. Thanks